# jQuery click events stopping works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. `jQuery('#FinishTest').click()` works, but it stops when you select all the answers. The error does not appear in the console.

[image: bugs]

my code

```
jQuery('#FinishTest').click(function() {

  var names = {};
  jQuery(':radio').each(function() {
    names[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = true;
  });
  var count = 0;
  jQuery.each(names, function() {
    count++;
  });

  if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length > 3) {
    if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length < count) {
      if (confirm("Henüz cevaplanmamış sorularınız var. Testi bitirmek istediğinizden eminmisiniz ?")) {
        finishtest();
      } else {
        jQuery('#FinishTest').bind('click');
        return;
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert('Testi bitirebilmek için en az 2 soru cevaplamalısınız.');
  }
});
```

Comment: If you remove the source @Kevin you should add an alternative to the question, else you should comment to make the author knows that he/she should...

Comment: The edit summary clearly summarizes the purpose of the edit and future actions that need to occur. it is not my place to make up an html example that demonstrates the OP's problem.

Comment: I do not think Kevin would understand the people's problems.

Comment: I do understand your problem, the problem I have with this question however is that the question will not demonstrate the problem once the problem is resolved, thus making it not useful for future visitors. All i'm asking is that you provide a working sample in your question that recreates your problem that will last longer than your problem does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happen because of the following condition in your code :

```
if( jQuery(':radio:checked').length < count )
```

When you select all the answers you will end up by `jQuery(':radio:checked').length` equals six `6` and the `count` variable value will be also `6` so the condition will never evaluates to true.

Try to add equal to you condition `=` so it will be inferior or equal `<=` :

```
if( jQuery(':radio:checked').length <= count ){
   //Your logic here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Changed and solved problem.

```js
if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length > 3) {
  if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length < count) {
    if (confirm("Henüz cevaplanmamış sorularınız var. Testi bitirmek istediğinizden eminmisiniz ?")) {
      finishtest();
    }
  } else {
    finishtest();
  }
} else {
  alert('Testi bitirebilmek için en az 2 soru cevaplamalısınız.');
}
```

Comment: I mean, we don't actually know what the count value would be without having the html sample. If you had 6 inputs, but between them there were only 3 unique names (multiple radio buttons for the same name) the count would be 3.

Comment: But either way you're right, the problem must be in the conditional logic.

Comment: Sorry but you could check that in the console of http://www.sorularicoz.net/mvc/quiz/hece-bilgisi-test-2 and the count is 6 not 3.

Comment: I mean, that's a link to a 3rd source that won't exist once this problem is resolved, i don't consider that to be part of the question.

Comment: Agreed.. but that should be a comment on the OP not a downvote on the answer.. isn't?

Comment: No, i've already cast a close vote to that effect. The comment was meant for this answer, due to the assumptions it makes.

Comment: I have no problem with my counter. counts right counter.

Comment: There's no assumptions, actually the answer is tested and works just fine and you could see that at  http://recordit.co/A1n3iv0O7u of test it by yourself ..

Comment: What browser are you using? When I do, the button is locked.

Comment: You may have to clear the cache of the browser. or use the private navigation to make sure this isn't a cache problem.

Comment: Thank you Zakaria i solved problem. i changed this code if(jQuery(':radio:checked').length > 3) {
     if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length < count) {
         if(confirm("Henüz cevaplanmamış sorularınız var. Testi bitirmek istediğinizden eminmisiniz ?")) {
       finishtest();
               }
           } else {
            finishtest();
           }
             } else {
              alert('Testi bitirebilmek için en az 2 soru cevaplamalısınız.');
             }

Answer (score -3):

There is no error in your code. Just only condition is wrong in if statement.
I have tested on my browser(chrome) with debug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kvje.png)

I hope it will be help you.